# Anyone tried DiffMerge as the default 3-way merge tool with Evolphin Zoom Version Control Client?

Tags: version-control, diff, versioning, flash-cs5, three-way-merge

So far we have been using the MacOS XCode FileMerge/OpenDiff tool as our default 3-way merge tool when resolving conflicts in text files with Evolphin Zoom. Has anyone tried using DiffMerge or other 3-way merging tools? I find FileMerge doing strange merges at time that don't make sense. Since Evolphin Zoom allows plugging in other merge tools, I wanted to see what are the best options on MacOS? Diffmerge is open source - has it worked well for you in complex merging scenarios?

Answer (score 1):

I have tried DiffMerge, Filemerge and a commercial tool I can't recollect the name. FileMerge seems like the best option. In an IDE setting I love IntelliJ's 3-way merge.